# gaeunit, /test link appears to be broken

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, gaeunit

I am trying to use geaunit in my gae project.  As is recommended, I have put the gaeunit.py file in my project root directory, added the required lines to app.yaml, and placed a test directory in the project root directory.

If I go to http://localhost:8080/test when I am logged in as an administrator I get "Oops! This link appears to be broken."

If I go to http://localhost:8080/test when not logged in as admin I get "Current logged in user test@example.com is not authorized to view this page."

app.yaml

```
application: myproject
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /static
static_dir: app/static 

- url: /test.*
login: admin  # This is important if you deploy the test directory in production!
script: gaeunit.py

- url: /.*
script: main.py
login: required
secure: always
```

Project structure

```
/myproject
    /app.yaml
    /gaeunit.py
    /test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: removing the *login:admin* what happens?

Comment: When I remove the login:admin I still get a broken link

Comment: I sort of figured it out.  Basically, my python environment was a mess.  So I booted up a virtual 32-bit Ubuntu-10.10 and ran my project in that.  It was a real pain setting up py2.5 on Ubuntu but now I have a script for setting the environment up. I no longer get a broken link when going to http://localhost:8080/test.